# Wireless Driver only AC not N

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.10

I'm running 16.10 on a Dell XPS 13 (9343). It uses the the `Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)` driver, but as you can see it only uses AC while the network card actually support N too. Why is this and how can I fix it? I used `bcmwl-kernel-source` to install the driver...

Comment: What is the real problem? `Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter` is the name of the adapter. Why do you think it can't work in 802.11n mode?

Comment: Well the problem is, I want to set my router to N-Only and all other devices support it, except for the driver on my laptop.

Comment: Why do you set it n only? Does the router support ac mode? What is the router channel? What is the encryption?

Answer (score 4):

The information '802.11ac' is hard-coded and is what is reported when you run `lspci` and others. It has nothing to do with the actual present connection speed. If you reset your router to 802.11b and then connect at a blazing 11 Mbps, the reading you see will still be '802.11ac'; it will not change to:

```
Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11b Wireless Network Adapter
```

It is a bad idea to set your router to 802.11n only. Many wireless driver and hardware combinations start slow and, if possible, negotiate up to 802.11n or even ac. Your driver and hardware combination is looking for a nice, easy 11 Mbps connection and, once it finds it and connects, will negotiate its way up.

The most reliable way I know of to determine what speed you have negotiated is:

```
iwconfig
```

Here is a sample from my machine:

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"GBR5"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: xx:2B:B0:DC:45:xx
      Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:835   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Well I'm a little concerned that the driver only uses AC while my NIC supports N...

Comment: `ac` is faster than `n`.  You probably think `n` is better )))

Comment: Does `iwconfig` confirm that it's using AC? What bit rate is reported.